# Dropdown values with hyperlinks to another page

Tags: php

The code below dynamically populates a dropdown with values from sql server database.

Is it possible to create hyperlink of the values in such that if you select any option from the dropdown, it passes the selected value to another page, say anwers.php?

```
<select name="Types" style="width:178px;">
 <option value=""></option>

 <?php
     $tsql = "select st.wills,st.types sc from [status][s]
left outer join [Wills][st] on s.id=st.wills
where st.types is not null and st.wills=1
group by st.types, st.wills
union all
select s.id,s.Status sc from [status][s]
left outer join [Wills][st] on s.id=st.wills where st.wills <> 8
group by s.id,s.Status";
     $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);
     if( $stmt === false )
     {
      echo "Error in executing query.</br>";
      die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
     }
      while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
       echo '<option value="' . $row['sc'] . '" name="' . $row['sc']. '">' . $row['sc']. '</option>';
     }
  ?>
 </select>
```

Thank you

UPDATE:

```
<form method="get" action="answer.php" target="SearchResults">
 <select id="Types" name="Types" style="width:178px;">
 <option value=""></option>
 <option value="wills" name="wills">wills</option>
 <option value="Library" name="Library">Library</option>
 <option value="gates" name="gates">gates</option>
 <option value="danes" name="danes"></option>
 <option value="Reviews" name="Reviews">Reviews</option>
 <option value="Closed" name="Closed">Closed</option>
 <option value="Pending" name="Pending">Pending</option></select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the select inside a form, like this:

```
<form id="FormTypes" method="get" action="answer.php">
    <select name="Types" id="Types" style="width:178px;">
    (...)
    </select>
</form>
```

And submit the form on the onchange event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload = function() {
       document.getElementById("Types").onchange = function() {
           document.getElementById("FormTypes").submit();
       }
   } 
</script>
```

Please note that you must add both the id and name attributes to the select tag for this to work.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response.

Is it possible to not click a submit button?

We would like to just select an option and it automatically redirects to answer.php

Comment: It already works the way you described, no submit buttons :) The form gets submited once you select an option.

Comment: That's precisely what I thought but when I select, nothing happens.
I have already given the <SELECT> an id and name attributes.

Comment: Can you post the HTML output by PHP? It'll make things a lot easier :)

Comment: I replaced my form with the one you provided and it worked. Do you jave any other JS code on the page? It may be interfering somehow... try running the example in an isolated file, with no extra JS, and check if it works for you. Also, which browser are you using to test it?

Comment: yes, I have a bunch other js codes for other controls.

Also, I don't know if this matters, there is already one <form>..</form> already on the page.

UPDATE:  I just ran it in isolation and it is still not going to the answer.php page.

And I am running IE 11.

I will test in isolated mode and let you know shortly.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Oh, having another form on the page matters a lot :) I've updated my code again, added an id to the form and used it to call submit() instead of the forms[0]. I believe changing this will make it work for you.

Comment: I don't mean to disappoint you  or even upset you for that matter but it is still not working.

I select from the dropdown and it just sits there.

I have run it alone with no other js or form or controls and I have also run it  with the rest of the other stuff. No luck.

Thanks for all your efforts.

UPDATE: Now it works. I had to clear cache.

Thanks so much for your wonderful help.

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/u3ofd17L/ just tested and it worked. Could you create another fiddle with your code and share it here? It'll make things easier.

Comment: It is working now as I updated in my last comment.

You have been incredibly patient. Thank you.

The only problem is it doesn't work when I put it back along with the other form and other js but I will figure this one out.

Comment: No problem! Glad it worked for you :) Just get back here in case you need help making it work inside the page.